# Default membership of SharePoint_Shell_Access?

Tags: 2013, 2016

According to the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863(v=office.16).aspx), one of the roles in the config database is "WSS_SHELL_ACCESS", and the setup account is set as a member. However, on my farm I see a "SharePoint_Shell_Access", and the farm account is a member. The docs list which roles the farm account will be in, but this role is not on that list. Are any or all of these differences a problem with the documentation or with my configuration procedures?

Comment: It looks like the documentation is incorrect. At the bottom of the article where it asks if it was helpful, click No and add comments. I've done this for this article, as well. Microsoft does act upon the comments supplied.